# Create domains via rest api (Google)

Tags: google-api

There is some way to create domains in google admin console via a rest api (or some python google-sdk). I search in google documentation but i couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look at their api. You need of course to be a gapps reseller. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an exemple with Node :

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/domains/latest

```js
import { DomainsClient } from "@google-cloud/domains";
const client = new DomainsClient({
  keyFile,
  projectId,
});
const [domainRegisterParameters] = await client.retrieveRegisterParameters({
  domainName: "example.com",
  location,
});
const registerParameters = domainRegisterParameters.registerParameters
await this.client.registerDomain({...}) // it buy the domain name
```

It seem to be this for python :
https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/domains/latest